# Proving that set A ≠ (Aᶜ)

Tags: lean

In Lean 4 I'm trying to prove that for any set it is the case that `s ≠ (sᶜ)`, and got the following:

```js
variable (s : Set α)

example (xInU: α) : s ≠ (sᶜ) := by
  intro n
  have ex : (xInU ∈ s) ∨ (xInU ∉ s) := em _
  have a1 : (xInU ∈ s) → False := fun inS => (n ▸ inS) inS
  have a2 : (xInU ∉ s) → False := fun ninS => (n ▸ ninS) ninS
  exact Or.elim ex a1 a2
```

I added the `xInU` hypothesis in order to have a witness for proceeding.

1. Can the proof be carried out without the `xInU` hypothesis?
2. Related, it is the case that Set.univ (for any type) have at least one element? (So a witness like `xInU` may always be put in context.) Maybe setting a "non empty" constraint to the α type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question, no, if your type is empty then it's not true.

```
import Mathlib

example (h : ∀ (α : Type) (s : Set α), s ≠ sᶜ) : False := by
  apply h Empty ∅
  ext x
  cases x
```

In particular, the type `Empty` is an example of an empty type.

There is a predicate called `Nonempty` that can be used to say that a type is nonempty. It's a `Prop` so it's the mere fact that a type is nonempty, rather than giving an explicit witness. Here's a quick modification to your example to use it:

```
example [Nonempty α] : s ≠ (sᶜ) := by
  inhabit α
  let xInU : α := default
  intro n
  have ex : (xInU ∈ s) ∨ (xInU ∉ s) := em _
  have a1 : (xInU ∈ s) → False := fun inS => (n ▸ inS) inS
  have a2 : (xInU ∉ s) → False := fun ninS => (n ▸ ninS) ninS
  exact Or.elim ex a1 a2
```

Here's a shorter proof using some higher-powered tactics:

```
example [Nonempty α] : s ≠ (sᶜ) := by
  inhabit α
  intro n
  have n' := congr(default ∈ $n)
  tauto
```

Comment: I have yet to read about `congr` with the dollar sign (can't find a reference.) Also I wonder why I can't add spaces after `congr`, like `congr   (default ∈ $n)`?

Comment: @DBE You can hover your mouse over `congr` for some of the documentation, but otherwise there's just the [Mathlib module documentation](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Mathlib/Tactic/TermCongr.html) and [its test file](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib4/blob/master/test/TermCongr.lean). It's relatively new. It takes an equality (like `n`) and generates what happens when `default ∈ _` is applied to both sides. The syntax is no spaces, otherwise `congr` is the lemma `congr`.

Comment: Thanks! I use VSCode and usually just press F12 to jump into the definition... currently congr takes me to Prelude (where there is an eponymous lemma), hence the confusion.

Comment: @DBE Wow, thanks for letting me know, that's very odd! It really ought to bring you to the definition of `congr(...)`. At least "go to declaration" brings you to the syntax declaration. (VSCode Lean hint: use "go to declaration" instead of "go to definition" if you want the syntax declaration.)